# Looking for some SQL help here

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, case

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableName](
    [ID] [varchar](24) NULL,
    [CNum] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,  
    [PageCnt] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CostPerPage] [money] NOT NULL,
    [TotalAmt] [money]  NULL,
    [Payment] [money]  NULL
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (ID,CNum,PageCnt,CostPerPage) VALUES ('ABC-0987654321',           '1',47,     0.12)   --5.64
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (ID,CNum,PageCnt,CostPerPage) VALUES ('ABC-0987654321',           '2',62,     0.12)   --7.44  
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (ID,CNum,PageCnt,CostPerPage) VALUES ('ABC-0987654321',           '3',52,     0.12)   --6.24  
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (ID,CNum,PageCnt,CostPerPage) VALUES ('ABC-0987654321',           '4',50,     0.12)   --6.00  
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (ID,CNum,PageCnt,CostPerPage) VALUES ('ABC-0987654321',           '5',63,     0.12)   --7.56  
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (ID,CNum,PageCnt,CostPerPage) VALUES ('ABC-1234567890',           '1',167,    0.12)   --20.04 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (ID,CNum,PageCnt,CostPerPage) VALUES ('ABC-1234567890',           '2',584,    0.12)   --70.08 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (ID,CNum,PageCnt,CostPerPage) VALUES ('ABC-1234567890',           '3',884,    0.12)   --106.08    
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (ID,CNum,PageCnt,CostPerPage) VALUES ('ABC-1234567890',           '4',1611,   0.12)   --193.32    
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (ID,CNum,PageCnt,CostPerPage) VALUES ('ABC-test0987654321',       '1',158,    0.12)   --18.96     
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (ID,CNum,PageCnt,CostPerPage) VALUES ('ABC-test1234567890',       '1',125,    0.12)   --15.00 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (ID,CNum,PageCnt,CostPerPage) VALUES ('ABC-test123456789012345',  '1',120,    0.12)   --14.4
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (ID,CNum,PageCnt,CostPerPage) VALUES ('ABC-7824156987',           '1',127,    0.12)   --15.24
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] (ID,CNum,PageCnt,CostPerPage) VALUES ('ABC-7824156987',           '2',44,     0.12)   --5.38      

SELECT 
     ID
    ,CNum
    ,PageCnt
    ,CostPerPage
    ,TotalAmt= PageCnt*CostPerPage
    ,Payment 
FROM [dbo].[TableName]
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: ["Can you help me?" isn't a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983) Ask us something we can actually answer. Explain the required logic. Show us your attempts, tell us why they didn't work. Perhaps tell us what research you performed and what about it you didn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a window sum and conditional logic:

```
select id, cnum, pagecnt, costperpage, pagecnt * costperpage as totalamt,
    case 
        when sum(pagecnt * costperpage) over(partition by id order by cnum) <= 15
            then pagecnt * costperpage
        when sum(pagecnt * costperpage) over(partition by id order by cnum) - pagecnt * costperpage <= 15
            then pagecnt * costperpage + 15 - sum(pagecnt * costperpage) over(partition by id order by cnum) 
        else 0
    end as payment
from tablename t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bae9c0825ecab3a2a580bfb5e4c74a91)**